# How can i show the radio field horizontally in my WooCommerce Checkout Page?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know how can i show the following custom radio checkout field horizontally instead of one below the other.

I want them to appear next to each other, similar to the image below [image]

They currently appear in my checkout form as the image below

[image]

I have used the following code to add the fields but i couldn't figure out how to align them horizontally & properly.

```html
/**
 * Simple checkout field addition example.
 * 
 * @param  array $fields List of existing billing fields.
 * @return array         List of modified billing fields.
 */
function hayder_add_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_address_type'] = array(
        'label'        => __( 'Address Type' ),
        'type'        => 'radio',
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
        'priority'     => 85,
        'class'        => array('address_type'),
        'required'     => true,
        'options'      => array(
        'Home'  => 'Home (9AM-9PM, All Days)',
        'Work'  => 'Work (9AM-6PM, Weekdays Only)',
        ),
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'hayder_add_checkout_fields' );

function hd_woocommerce_admin_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_address_type'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Address Type' ),
        'show' => true,
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'hd_woocommerce_admin_billing_fields' );
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you post a link to your site? I think this is more a CSS question.

Comment: This is my website --> https://qonooz.com